# How to create a priceConflicts hash like on store package configure

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Context:

On softlayer configure page for a virtual guest ( https://www.softlayer.com/Store/orderComputingInstance/1640,1644,2202 ), the JavaScript do a lot of show / hide on price items based on some restrictions like:

- MySQL for Linux is hidden when you choose Windows as Operating System (price to price restriction)
- Private Node are unavailable on Dallas (location to price restriction)

My Problem:

Building a web interface to configure a virtual guest, I need to build a hash exactly like `priceConflicts` that is shown on configure page.

calling `SoftLayer_Product_Package.getItemLocationConflicts` I can get the location to price restrictions, but when I call `SoftLayer_Product_Package.getItemConflicts` is returned an array of `SoftLayer_Product_Item_Resource_Conflict_Item` with 4 attributes `itemId`, `packageId`, `resourceTableId` and `message`, that is exactly what is describe for http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Resource_Conflict_Item

Some things that are weird:

- According to documentation: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemConflicts return values was supposed to be an array of SoftLayer_Product_Item_Resource_Conflict, not an array of SoftLayer_Product_Item_Resource_Conflict_Item
- According to documenation: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Resource_Conflict_Item there's a resource relational property, but when I call with a mask `mask[resource]` the following error is returned: Property 'resource' not valid for 'SoftLayer_Product_Item_Resource_Conflict'.

So, how do I get the information needed to create a struct like `priceConflicts` hash?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both cases it returns an array of [SoftLayer_Product_Item_Resource_Conflict](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Resource_Conflict)

You need to assume

- For
  [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemLocationConflicts](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemLocationConflicts)
  method, the "itemId" has a "location conflict" with the location
  which has the same identifier as "resourceTableId".

  You can retrieve location identifiers with the following method:
  [SoftLayer_Location_Datacenter::getDatacenters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Datacenter/getDatacenters).
  So you will need to match the identifier, to get the location
- For
  [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemConflicts](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemConflicts)
  method, the "itemId" has conflicts with "resourceTableId" which
  corresponds another "itemId". You should match these values with the
  result from
  [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItems](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems)

> As your said, JavaScript does a lot of show / hide on price items
>   based on some restrictions.

I can provide a Python script which will help you to get all of this information

> Updated

```
"""
Get item prices information

This script retrieves information of prices from a package. It retrieves the item description,
location conflicts, pricing location group and item conflicts

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getRegions
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

@License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
@Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer
from prettytable import PrettyTable
# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
# Declare the image template id
packageId = 46
# Create a client instance
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
# Declare an object mask to get location conflicts
objectMask = 'mask[pricingLocationGroup[locations],item[locationConflicts, conflicts]]'

try:
    locations = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getRegions(id=packageId)
    items = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItems(id=packageId)
    print('*****  AVAILABLE LOCATIONS  *****')
    for location in locations:
        print('Id: %s,  Location: %s' % (location['location']['location']['id'], location['location']['location']['longName']))
    itemPrices = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItemPrices(id=packageId, mask=objectMask)
    items = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItems(id=packageId, mask='mask[prices]')
    x = PrettyTable(["Price Id", "Item Id", "Description", "Datacenter conflicts", "Pricing Location", 'Price conflicts', 'Item conflicts'])
    x.align["Price Id"] = "l"  # Left align city names
    x.padding_width = 1
    for price in itemPrices:
        dcConflicts = ''
        pricingLocation = ''
        conflictItems = ''
        conflictPrices = ''
        # Get location conflicts
        if  len(price['item']['locationConflicts']) > 0:
            for locationConflicts in price['item']['locationConflicts']:
                for location in locations:
                    if locationConflicts['resourceTableId'] == location['location']['location']['id']:
                        dcConflicts = dcConflicts + ' ' + location['location']['location']['longName']
        else:
            dcConflicts = "None"
        # Get Pricing location
        if 'pricingLocationGroup' in price:
            for priceLocation in price['pricingLocationGroup']['locations']:
                pricingLocation = pricingLocation + ' ' + priceLocation['longName']
        else:
            pricingLocation = 'Standard price'
        # Get item conflicts
        if len(price['item']['conflicts']) > 0:
            for conflict in price['item']['conflicts']:
                for item in items:
                    if conflict['resourceTableId'] == item['id']:
                        conflictItems = conflictItems + ' ' + str(conflict['resourceTableId'])
                        for priceConf in item['prices']:
                            conflictPrices = conflictPrices + ' ' + str(priceConf['id']) 
        if conflictItems == '':
            conflictItems = 'None'
            conflictPrices = 'None'
        x.add_row([price['id'], price['item']['id'], price['item']['description'], dcConflicts, pricingLocation, conflictPrices, conflictItems])
    print(x)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get item prices faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

Comment: hi Ruber, this is what I was doing, but if you check, the ids are weird, for example, priceId 40318 (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition) - checked on configure page, is right, on priceConflicts hash has id 22371 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.x - Minimal Install (32 bit)) but the python script you posted does not show this id (the bigger number is 4258) this is my difficult, how match the ids from your python script to price items. thank you

Comment: now I'm starting to understand, would like to check one information: for price id 40318 there is 227 conflicts, but when I try to match items for virtual guest (package 46) just match 32 items, the other 195 why they aren't found, because they are from other packages?

Comment: I can get item for a conflict, but I still can't map price id to price ids conflicting :/

Comment: You are trying to match "itemId" between "priceId". The script that I provided, displays information about items, you need to match these "ids" with the response for [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices) ("item >> id" from each price). The portal works with Prices, so it means portal does some internal processes to take the prices for items.

Comment: Finally, I updated the code in order to show information about price conflicts that each item has. Try to match again please, Let me know if you have any question, doubt or comments, in order to improve it.

Comment: TADA! now we got the same result (the missing resource table ids are probably from other packages)... now I'm pretty sure I have the right information and can manipulate to create a hash like the config store! thank you for all the support Ruber!